# Need a Way to Take a String and Find and Replace Certain Components

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to create a way of calculating some basic equations. I am trying to use eval() in the process to do the actual calculating (security precautions aren't necessary. I am not storing anything on this page and if they hack using the calculator, they won't affect any other people's version of the page.) The program mostly works but has a few flaws that I am trying to fix. One of these problems is that I want you to be able to put in an equation like this and have it calculated correctly; 2(2). Currently eval() tries to run 2 as a function and gives me an error. The solution path I thought of is replacing the left parentheses with left parentheses with a multiplication symbol in front, unless their is a addition or subtraction sign on the front. Example; I need this "2(2)" to transfer to this "2*(2)" when the code is run but I want this "2+(2)" to not transfer at all. My code is below. I already transferred the parentheses to a something easier to use code-wise. I have already tried several attempts and know that the parentheses are sometimes read as invalid. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PlayBox</title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            resize: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
        }
        body{
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
        function run() {
            var input = document.getElementById('input').value
            var simpPositive = input.search('[simp]')
            if (simpPositive > -1) {
                var equationb = input.replace('[simp]', '')
                var equationChangePara = equationb.replace('(', '&ahdt&')
                var findPara = equationChangePara.search('&ahdt&')
                // code here?
                var simp = eval(equationb)
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Both of your solutions worked wonderfully. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to rewrite strings that match your multiplication pattern of n(n). Something like this:

```
equationb = equationb.replaceAll(/(\d+)(\(\d+\))/g, "$1*$2");
```

For this code, if `equationb` contains string `2(2)`, it will get transformed to `2*(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find parentheses that are "sandwiched" between two numbers or a left parenthesis and a number, and replace them with `*(`.

```js
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
function myFunction(input) {
  var newInput = input.replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(");
  console.log(newInput)
  console.log(eval(newInput));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="boo"></input>
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction(boo.value)">Run</button>
```